# How to create a WCF MessageFault

Tags: c#, wcf, soapfault

I see two ways to create a MessageFault:

```
   FaultException fe = new FaultException("error");
   MessageFault f = fe.CreateMessageFault();
```

Or

```
   FaultCode fc = new FaultCode("error");
   MessageFault f = MessageFault.CreateFault(fc, "error");
```

What's the difference b/w two? Is anyone preferred?

Comment: You could try sending a WCF message, then immediately afterwards, take scissors to your cat-5 cable.

Answer (score 1):

There are many more ways to create a `MessageFault` than that. See [`MessageFault` members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messagefault_members.aspx).

All of these create an instance of the `MessageFault` class. The documentation tells you how they differ.